# Check for data correctness Oracle ETL

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, etl, correctness

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we check for misspelled or inaccurate data in the target system as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

Comment: I think this will be very complex to do with Oracle. You can pull the data from your data base and use a tool like talend open studios for  etl and verify for correctness.

Comment: Please make sure your questions include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

In other words, what have you tried yourself so far to solve your dilemma?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes I have tried to solve it myself but could not. I have a set of questions to ask. I will with some example this time. Thanks